# Is there a feature in matlab like background worker?

Tags: c#, matlab

I need something like background worker in C# to use in matlab. fyi `drawnow` will not be useful because I don't want the background thread in GUI. I need it in processing.

so, Is there something like that in matlab?

thanks.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8919-smartsilent-figure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something completely like the back ground worker in `C#` ..

`t = timer('TimerFcn',@(x,y)disp(clock),'StartDelay',5,'ExecutionMode','fixedSpacing');`

`start(t)`

The back ground thread will run after 5 seconds and displays the output of `clock` function.
`'fixedSpacing'` means that it will run automatically after it ends.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Not really.  Matlab is almost entirely a single threaded environment.

There are a few caveats associated with that.

1. Some aspects of worked threads can be accomplished by a clever use of Timer objects.  One item is executing at a a time, either a timer object or the main execution activity.  Timers will not interrupt each other, but they can interrupt the main execution thread.  So you could put the expensive operation in the main activity and some maintenance activities in timers.

   Determining what functions can be interrupted by Timers is tricky.  My best effort to figure it out is in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15695808/931379).  I've worked with Mathworks on this and determined there is really no satisfying answer.
2. Java methods can be executing from the event dispatch thread.  See `javaMethodEDT`.  (This probably doesn't help you, but I'm trying to optimize my Matlab/threading speech.)
3. External programs, (e.g. Java, C, C# etc) can bring their own threads.  These programs can be run from Matlab.